# Adding a namespace to existing XDocument

Tags: linq-to-xml

I need to manipulate some xml files using Linq to xml.

I have an existing XDocument that I Load

Now I cannot seem to be able to add a namespace to it.

I do:

```
//Load an existing xml into a XDocument
XDocument xdoc=XDocument.Load(myXml);

//Create a namespace
 XNamespace myNS="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/MyShinyNewNamespace";
 xAttribute myAttr=new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns +"myNS",myNS);

  //Add new namepsace to root

 xdoc.Root ????

What do you do here?
```

How do I retrieve my namespace?

How do I Remove/Replace?

many thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, while XML markup allows you to use

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns">
  <foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

to use a single namespace declaration attribute to put the root element as well as those descendant elements into the declared namespace, when you manipulate the tree model you need to change the `Name` of all elements so you need e.g.

```
XNamespace myNs = "http://example.com/ns";

foreach (XElement el in xdoc.Descendants()) 
{
  el.Name = myNs + el.Name.LocalName;
}
```

If you also want to set a certain prefix `pf` then addionally set

```
  xdoc.Root.Add(new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "pf", myNs));
```

Answer (score 0):

To add dynamically from one xdocument to another one see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx